# Show average in highcharts graph as column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want some table at the top of my scatter graph, but can't find out how to do this. What I currently have is an scatter graph with data, see (http://jsfiddle.net/uynp3svh/). What I want is to show the average value between the two hours. It is not possible to use the tooltip, because the graph is already using the tooltip.

[image: Graph with average]

I tried solving this with adding the following table and place it at the right place with some css. But when resizing the screen, the table is not at the right place anymore. So this is not the best solution.

```
<div id="table">
  <div class="inner-table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>3.95</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: You could do this with another x axis - use the labels formatter to fetch the appropriate value from an external array of the values you want displayed.  You could do it with plotlines, using their label, you could do it by adding an additional scatter series, and adding a data label.  I would probably opt for the axis labels myself.

Comment: Do you have an example of doing this with another x axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using an additional x axis to accomplish this.

It requires that you have an array of time stamps, and an array of the values that want to display, ie:

```
var averages = [
    10,
    12,
    0.8,
    4,
    8,
    null,
    2,
    null,
    3.95,
    11,
    null,
    21
  ],
  times = [
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 3, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 5, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 9, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 11, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 13, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 15, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 17, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 19, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 21, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 23, 0),
    Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 23, 0)
  ];
```

Then it's just a matter of using the times array to set the tickPositions, and the averages array for the axis label values.

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/uynp3svh/3/

Again, this is just one of many ways.

Any way that you do it, having the array of times, and the array of values, will be key.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. There are indeed many ways to do this, but I also want the values always on the same place, even when I resize the window. So for me is this a great solution.